# Posting String to server (Android)

Tags: java, android, json, string, api

I am posting string as a interest . But when i do i gets following response :

```
{"events":[["waiting"],["connected"],["commonLikes",["r","o","n","h","y"]],["identDigests","6705753b57f508f0c26abbd016ac54e5,2ac2f44c3ea3b8578fe95311b141a0b4,6705753b57f508f0c26abbd016ac54e5,2ac2f44c3ea3b8578fe95311b141a0b4"]],"clientID":"central2:wgg1nvmbv92s1xo9ygg503ene0tq8n"}
```

I am posting just like this :

```
String str= "\"Rohny\"";
```

I want commonlikes looks like this :

```
["Rohny"]
```

Server php function :

```
when ('commonLikes') {
        $om->fire('commonlikes', $event[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
&quot;
```

in palce of

```
\"
```

Comment: How can you give me example ??

Comment: Can i use "&quotRohny&quot" just like this ?? in  java class or something else ??